# Selecting values from a view based on a specific row's value

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to write a query where I am selecting all rows from a table where a column (lets call it "ESA") is equal to the ESA of a specific "CASE_ID".

The best I can come up with is:

```
SELECT *, :case_id.ESA as ESA_VAL FROM V_NRF_TABLE_TE
WHERE ESA = ESA_VAL.ESA;
```

Any pointers welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer:

```
SELECT * FROM V_NRF_TABLE_TE
WHERE ESA = (
SELECT ESA FROM V_NRF_TABLE_TE WHERE CASE_ID = :case_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `:case_id.ESA` in where clause

```
SELECT * FROM V_NRF_TABLE_TE
WHERE ESA = :case_id.ESA
```

Comment: Thanks, that's giving me this error though:

ORA-22806: not an object or REF
22806. 00000 -  "not an object or REF"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to extract an attribute from an item that is
           neither an object nor a REF.
*Action:   Use an object type or REF type item and retry the operation.